# How to add read access to Application Insights to built in Reader role?

Tags: azure

User needs to have read only access to two subscriptions, so added user to the Access 
Control for both subscriptions and gave them the built in role [Readers]. Basically I want the user to be able to view Application Insights but not to create, delete, update anything else.

The user reported that they could not AI and instead saw this.

[image]

Digging into this error I got this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/troubleshooting) from MS.

The pertinent information is:

These items require write access to the whole Resource group that contains your website:

TLS/SSL Certificates and bindings (TLS/SSL certificates can be shared between sites in the same resource group and geo-location)

Alert rules

Autoscale settings

**Application insights components**

Web tests

I think the best way to proceed is to create a role that is the same as the built in Reader, and then assign write rights to Application Insights, add this role to the user, and remove the built-in reader. I am knew to Azure and would appreciate any advice or recommendation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to grant the user with both *Reader* and *Application Insights Component Contributor* roles. For full list of built-in roles, see [Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles).

Comment: I spoke too soon. Confirmed that user still cannot see Application Insights. Another way to accomplish what I want to do is to make the user a contributor, but deny delete rights. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Based on the permissions actions of role Application Insights Component Contributor, granted user should have rights to manage Application Insights components. Had the user signed out and then signed in again? Some privileges assignments often takes effect after re-sign in.

Comment: Huodong, yes I had the user sign in and out, as that is often necessary. It didn't help. I sent in a support ticket with MS, as I think that I have followed your steps and I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler Any luck with support? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: It has been so long ago now that I cannot remember. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is lack of Contributor permission to the azrscoccwebapiqa01 App Service itself, not the Application Insights for that service. The Application Insights tab on the App Service requires being able to read the settings in the App Service configuration to know which Application Insights to display on the tab. The user will instead need to go directly to the Application Insights resource itself, not via the App Service.

Answer (score 0):

How about this role https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/roles-permissions-security#monitoring-reader

It allows for:

```
- Access Application Insights data and view data in Application Insights Analytics.
```

Let me know if you've found some other solution.

I have somewhat similar task: provide user with readonly access to Application Insights, but without using Contributor role or custom roles.